# Learning performance boost after loading a model

Tags: python, keras, model, load

I'm training an LSTM model which usually is hitting a plateau and fails to fully converge (about one in ten converge in the initial run). However, if I load the pre-trained model there is always huge learning improvement right away even without adjusting the learning rate. What is that caused by? How come there is huge performance improvement even though in the first run algorithm was stuck on a plateau for 60+ epochs?
I used Adam optimizer with default learning rate.

loss function for initial training
[image: 1]

loss function after loading model
[image: 2]